# Laravel 5.5 issue arise during updating form values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In **web.php** under routes directory, I defined a route: `Route::resource('myprofile','Administrator\MyProfileController');`

In my **controller**, I have the update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
// bla bla 
}
```

In my blade file, I have the below code;

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'administrator/myprofile', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
  // bla bla bla
{{ Form::close() }}
```

After submitting the form, I see the following error;

> Method [store] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Administrator\MyProfileController].

Here, I do not want to store/insert the form values. These are already in the db table. I just want to update the form values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that your controller does not implement the store member function.

A POST request to a resource controller calls upon the store method of that controller.

To send an UPDATE request you have to override the request method in your html form like so:

```
<!-- _id : the resource id you want to update. -->
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'administrator/myprofile/_id', 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
  // bla bla bla
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It now redirect to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/administrator/myprofile but show error - Undefined variable: e

Comment: Okay, I have to pass the ID like administrator/myprofile/1 . Solved. Thanks